# Align button to bottom of absolute DIV dialog

Tags: css, button, dialog, vertical-alignment, absolute

Everywhere people asks for how to align an element inside a DIV they are told that the container must have a `relative` position.
In my case, I have a floating dialog, with `absolute` position. How can I make a button element always stick to the bottom of this dialog?

```
<div class="dialog">
    <div class="dialog-content">
    </div>
    <button>Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the CSS, otherwise I am guessing which elements are floated or absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `absolute` positioning with `bottom: 0px` for your button. It will position relative to the parent of `button` which is `.dialog`.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/0rohooj9/

Answer (score 2):

You would need to give the dialog absolute dimensions, and then set the button's `position` to `absolute`, and `bottom: 0`;

Here's a **Fiddle** with your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/erlingormar/d8sa43s8/

Comment: That works until you add a second button. They overlap each other

Comment: How about this then? :)

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/erlingormar/d8sa43s8/ (You can exchange the 0-values (for `left` and `right`) with pixel-values or percentages if you need even more buttons).